# **string' : ambiguous symbol**

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010

I am trying an example code from CS50 class, when I run the following code I get an error message about the string (**string' : ambiguous symbol**). i am using Visual Studio. 
Please help

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cs50.h"
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
void PrintName(string name);
int main(void)
{
    printf("Your Name:");
    string s = GetString();
    PrintName(s);
    cin.get();
}
void PrintName(string name)
{
    printf("hello, %s\n", name);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to `#include <string>`? And why the mix of C and C++ I/O?

Comment: No idea what "CS50 class" is or how it's relevant.

Comment: CS50 appears to be a computer science course that apparently teaches horribly outdated methods and dangerous code. Lovely!

Comment: `cs50.h` contains `typedef char *string;`  , so if you are going to use this then you should not do `using namespace std;` .

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why you're using this `#include "cs50.h"` actually<sup>1</sup>, but I'd seriously recommend keeping with the following points:

1. Omit `using namespace std;` rather say `void PrintName(const std::string& name);` (`const` and reference `&`, is because you won't change the passed `std::string` parameter, when just printing it).
2. If you really want to use `printf()` rather than `std::cout` for c++, print `std::string` instances like follows:

---

```
void PrintName(const std::string& name) {
    printf("hello, %s\n", name.c_str());
}
```

---

3. The usual way to print strings in c++ is

---

```
void PrintName(std::ostream& os, const std::string& name) {
    os << "hello" << name << std::endl;
}
```

4. You don't show what `GetString();` actually does, but I'd suspect the signature and implementation rather should be:

---

```
std::string GetString(std::istream& is) {
    std::string result;
    std::getline(is,result);
    return result;
}
```

---

and call

```
int main(void) {
    std::cout << "Your Name: ";
    std::string s = GetString(std::cin);
    PrintName(std::cout,s);
    std::cin.get();
}
```

---

5. Don't forget to `#include <string>` if you have code referring to `std::string`

---

See the [***FULLY WORKING SAMPLE***](http://ideone.com/RfxdJy) please.

---

1) As far I can see the very 1st few lines of that header file (["cs50.h"](http://dkui3cmikz357.cloudfront.net/library50/c/cs50-library-c-3.0/cs50.h)) just makes up a `typedef` for `string` that will **miserably fail** with any of the intended `std::string` operations:

```
/*
 * Our own data type for string variables.
 */

typedef char *string;
```

That's considered a ***very bad design*** and I'd recommend just to put that crap it into the trash bin, where it belongs.
Anyway, you can overcome it, if you really think needing such included, by just omitting the `using namespace std;` statement to avoid any ambiguities beforehand.